# HTML5 Canvas Ghosting Issue

Tags: html, canvas

When a user drags their cursor across the screen a square canvas is drawn. My issue is that the canvas is "ghosting". I think it is possible to fix this problem using redraw() or clearrect() but I'm not sure how to implement those functions in this case. Thanks.

```
drawSquare = true;
//DRAG TO CREATE RECTANGLE

if(drawSquare == true){
    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        dragShape = true;
        posYdown = e.pageY;
        posXdown = e.pageX;
    });
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
            if(dragShape == true) {
                var c=document.getElementById("canvas1");
                var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.fillRect(posXdown ,posYdown ,e.pageX - posXdown ,e.pageY - posYdown);           
            }
        });
            $(document).mouseup(function() {
                dragShape = false;
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need `context.clearRect` to remove previously drawn pixels or you will have ghost remnants.

Here's a refactored version of your code:

Hints:

- Clear the canvas before drawing a new rectangle.
- Just get references to your canvas and context once at the beginning of your app.
- Adjust your mouse position by the offset X,Y of the canvas (in case you later reposition your canvas on the page).

Good luck with your learning!

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

var dragShape=false;
var posXdown,posYdown;



function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  posXdown=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  posYdown=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  dragShape = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dragShape = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!dragShape){return;}
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  var width=mouseX-posXdown;
  var height=mouseY-posYdown;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(posXdown,posYdown,width,height);           

}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```